# How to access the database of a Dynamics 365 business central cloud service?

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

Is it possible to access the SQL server database of a Dynamics 365 business central directly or can I access it only via APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to get direct access to SQL from BC cloud. You would need to use the native connector to Business Central. Alternatively you could consider the Web Services page in Business Central or the API.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to review the link below, maybe it can help;

https://demiliani.com/2020/05/15/read-scale-out-with-azure-sql-and-dynamics-365-business-central/

Ugur

Comment: Good! This link shows that you can in a way access directly the database but didn't explain how...

Comment: The blog owner answered my comment there saying that it's not possible also. So thanks for it!